# Summing rows with same ID in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Symbol| profit | person 
AAPL    +723     A
AAPL    -100     B
BBY     +123     A
NTAP    +513     A
```

I want to select the top n and bottom n symbols by profit (ignoring whether it was person A or B). Thus, AAPL should come first and should show a profit of 623.

... in sql server

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
SELECT TOP 15 sym profit FROM x
GROUP BY sym, profit
ORDER BY profit DESC
```

Comment: What data type is the `profit` field?

Comment: If you want the top fifteen followed by the bottom fifteen you probably need two queries along the lines of your example with a `UNION` between them.

Comment: @Polly I'm ok running the top and bottom as separate queries

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
(
SELECT TOP 15
       Symbol,
       SUM(Profit)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Symbol
ORDER BY SUM(Profit)
) UNION (
SELECT TOP 15
       Symbol,
       SUM(Profit)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Symbol
ORDER BY SUM(Profit) DESC
)
```

Comment: Is this not sufficient? SELECT TOP 15
       Symbol,
       SUM(Profit)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Symbol
ORDER BY SUM(Profit)... Why the UNION?

Comment: Your question sounded like you wanted the top and bottom results appended to each other. If not, just remove the brackets and the UNION from this answer and that's your two queries.

Comment: Yes, the union was because the OP wanted both the top and bottom 15 entries. It's not needed if only the top 15 are needed. If separate queries are fine then the two parts can be run separately without the union as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GROUP BY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
SELECT Symbol, SUM(profit) FROM the_table GROUP BY Symbol;
```

**Note:** Add a `WHERE` clause to limit records if needed.

Comment: This does not work for me... unsure why. I should perhaps mention that there are other columns such as "As of Date"

Comment: You'd need to `ORDER BY SUM(Profit)` too.